# Apache RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters "FilesMatch"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-headers

This is my `.htaccess` file in the head

```
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
    RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.pdf $ - [E=FILENAME:$1]
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/wp-content/themes/my_theme/pdf/fr/.*#">
        Header add Link '<https://www.example.com/wp-content/my_theme/theme_SES/pdf/fr/%{FILENAME}e>; rel="canonical"'
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

And I'm receiving the following error in the `error.log`:

```
RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
```

What's wrong with the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: "This is my .htaccess file in the head" - What do you mean exactly by "in the head"? Do you mean in the "document root"? (Although yhis could be simplified further if you created the rule in a `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory in question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.pdf $ - [E=FILENAME:$1]
> ------------------------^
> ```

You have an erroneous *space* before the `$`. So the `-` is being seen as the *flags* (3rd) argument, hence the error.

It should be written like this:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.pdf$ - [E=FILENAME:$1]
```

---

*Aside:* You should be OK in this instance, but note the following [warning from the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> Although rewrite rules are syntactically permitted in `<Location>` and `<Files>` sections (including their regular expression counterparts), this should never be necessary and is unsupported. A likely feature to break in these contexts is relative substitutions.

For example, your code block could be rewritten more simply as:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/my_theme/pdf/fr/(?:.+/)?([^/]+)\.pdf$ - [E=FILENAME:$1]
Header add Link '<https://www.example.com/wp-content/my_theme/theme_SES/pdf/fr/%{FILENAME}e>; rel="canonical"' env=FILENAME
```

This could perhaps be simplified further knowing your actual URL structure.

And, depending on your other directives, you may need to change `FILENAME` in the `Header` directive to `REDIRECT_FILENAME`. (Depending on whether there is a loop by the rewrite engine - which there usually is if the standard WordPress directives are being used.)

Note the addition of the `env=FILENAME` argument on the `Header` directive, which sets this header conditionally on whether the `FILENAME` env var is set.

Comment: Thank's you ! i follow this tutorial https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/crawling-indexing/put-rel-canonical-on-non-html-resources and i dont notice the erroneous space