# Set Header with query_string data- apache2

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, query-string

I am running Apache and I am trying to set a header `Content-Security-Policy` = `X` only when the request has a variable `shop=X` on the query string. I would like something like this in my htaccess:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /shop=.*?/">
    Header set Content-Security-Policy 'X'
</If>
```

How can I get the `X` value of the query when I set the Header?

Comment: What directives do you already have in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I don't think you can somehow insert a "back reference" to what the if condition pattern matched here, as you would in a URL rewriting context. But `Header` can use an environment variable with the `%{VARNAME}e` syntax, so you should be able to create one based on your query string, using `SetEnvIf`.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use mod_rewrite to set an environment variable based on the query string and set the `header` conditionally on whether this env var is set and also use this env var in the header value itself. (You can't use `SetEnvIf` here since `SetEnvIf` cannot access the query string part of the URL.)

For example, the following sets and uses a `SHOP_VALUE` env var:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Set SHOP_VALUE env var to value of "shop" URL parameter (if any)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)shop=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SHOP_VALUE:%1]

# Set header conditionally on whether SHOP_VALUE is set and use this in the header value
# NB: You might need to use REDIRECT_SHOP_VALUE here instead depending on other directives
Header set Content-Security-Policy %{SHOP_VALUE}e env=SHOP_VALUE
```

As per the code comment above, you may need to change `SHOP_VALUE` in the `Header` directive to `REDIRECT_SHOP_VALUE`. This is dependent on whether you have other mod_rewrite directives that trigger a "loop" (eg. a front-controller pattern) - at which time env vars are renamed with a `REDIRECT_` prefix. (Alternatively, on Apache 2.4 you can use a *hard* `END` flag on `RewriteRule` directives, instead of `L`, to prevent a "loop" and a second pass by the rewrite engine.)

Note that I'm only matching non-empty values of the `shop` URL parameter. An empty `shop` URL parameter is ignored. The `%1` backreference in the first rule contains the value of `shop` URL parameter as captured in the preceding *CondPattern*. Note that this value is URL-encoded.

Note the addition of the `env=SHOP_VALUE` argument on the `Header` directive, which sets this header conditionally on whether the `SHOP_VALUE` env var is set. (It's not set when the `shop` URL parameter was not present and has no value in the query string.)

See also:

- [Apache RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters "FilesMatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792191/apache-rewriterule-bad-flag-delimiters-filesmatch)

*Aside/Warning:* The `Content-Security-Policy` response header allows you to control what resources a given user-agent is able to load. However, if you are giving the user-agent the ability to directly control the value of this header then any "security" this header provides is effectively bypassed.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /shop=.*?/">
> ```

This regex just checks for the string "shop=" anywhere in the query string, including where `shop` could appear as part of another URL parameter, eg. `fooshop=`.